# Search for two sequential patterns with any number of characters in between using grep

Tags: shell-script, grep

I want to look for lines with "word1 ... word2" where '...' could be any different characters. So far I have used two greps for the same like this:

`grep "$word1" $filename | grep "$word2"`

Is there a faster way to do this by suppose something like this:

`grep "$word1*$word2" $filename`

where maybe * could be some special character which can be any other character(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.*`:

```
grep "${word1}.*${word2}" "$filename"
```

- `.` matches any character
- `*` matches any number of the preceding character

Comment: More precisely, `.*` matches any chararacter repeated 0 or more times (IOW, it matches any string, including the empty string).

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you need the two words to be *delimited*, i.e. if you do *not* want to match `abba` if one of the words is `bb`, then use

```
grep "\\<$word1\\>.*\\<$word2\\>" "$filename"
```

The pattern `\<` (here `\\<` to escape the first backslash from the shell) matches just before a word, and `\>` works similarly but just after a word.

There's alo `\b` that matches either before and after, and `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` that work just like `\<` and `\>`.  Which ones that are implemented by `grep` varies.